# Cartesian product defined using unions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is a double union equal to a cartesian product of sets X and Y? In symbols:
$$X\times Y=\bigcup_{x\in X}\bigcup_{y\in Y}\{(x, y)\}$$

It seems like it should result in the same set of elements

Comment: Write $\{(x,y) \}$ instead, then yes. (Also, this is not an equivalence but an equality.)

Comment: Ah yes, I agree, that is ill-defined, will edit. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @Kcronix The relation you present is correct, since ultimately for any set $A$ one trivially has that $A=\displaystyle\bigcup_{x \in A} \{x\}$. In the particular case of a cartesian product $M \times N$, the generic element $u \in M \times N$ further has the form $u=(x, y)$, with $x \in M$ and $y \in N$, and that is essentially what is happening here.